# How is it possible to consume two arrays at the same time while iterating them with zip?

Tags: rust

How is it possible to consume two arrays at the same time?  `zip` will only give references while I need the actual objects to add them in a map.

```
let array1 : &[String] = &["abc".to_string(),"bcd".to_string()]
let array2 : &[String] = &["bcd".to_string(),"abc".to_string()]


for a,b in array1.into_iter().zip(array2.into_iter()){
  map.insert(a,b); // Doesn't work because a and b are &String instead of String
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your variables `array1` and `array2` are not arrays, they are immutable references to slices, similar but not the same. You cannot take ownership of data hidden behind an immutable reference. As such, `.into_iter()` will yield `&String`s, the fault is not due to `.zip()`.

What you want is something like this:

```
let array1 = ["abc".to_string(), "bcd".to_string()];
let array2 = ["bcd".to_string(), "abc".to_string()];

for (a, b) in array1.into_iter().zip(array2.into_iter()) {
    map.insert(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. What if I was to call a function that does the insert ? I have to pass the immutable references as arguments

Comment: @aliruk Why do you have to use references?

Comment: `fn func(arg : &[T])` would work but with `arg : [T]` the compiler would not know the size of the array

Comment: You can certainly have a function do the inserts, but what you pass can't be behind a reference. [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2cd8632c269b567d559ad2f58ff3af41) are some examples of different ways to do it depending on your desired flexibility: via fixed-size-arrays, generic-sized-arrays, vec, or iterator.